# How to create create/update .json file using EXTJS 4?

Tags: json, extjs4

I have one very simple html page containing 3 text fields and one save button. On click of the save button I just want to save the entered value as json data into "test.json" file.
And I am using EXTJS 4.
I have just started learning EXTJS4, so if anybody code examples that will be GREAT. :-)
Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

you could make a string like this

```
{"data":[{"firstname":"Jeans","lastname":"Louis","job":"developper"}]}
```

and save it to a file

Or you could use the build in feature, this is from the ExtJs API

```
Modified version of Douglas Crockford"s json.js that doesn"t mess with the Object prototype http://www.json.org/js.html
Defined By
Methods

Ext.JSON
view source
decode( String json, [Boolean safe] ) : Object
Decodes (parses) a JSON string to an object. ...

Ext.JSON
view source
encode( Mixed o ) : String
Encodes an Object, Array or other value ...

Ext.JSON
view source
encodeDate( Date d ) : String
Encodes a Date. ...
```

eg

```
var elemt = Ext.JSON.encode('your Object')
```

About the writing to a file, i suppose you mean on the server ? On the client that would be problematic..

Comment: Yes I want wite to server side ".json" file. How can we do it??

Comment: well, that depends on which server and OS you are using and which language you use, ASP, JSP, Ruby, PHP etc, should have more info about that. ExtJs normally communicates with a serverscript that saves the receiverd data in a database.

Comment: Hmmm...Just need to confirm do you mean we can not create/update any (in this case ".json") server side file from only EXTJS4..and for this we need to use our programing language e.g. java in my case..????

Comment: @Parag: Yes, that's what peter means. Client-side cannot save the json file (on client machine), so it needs to post the changed data (i.e. updated json) back to server in order to be saved on server machine.

Comment: the one exception is when you use WSH (only available in internet explorer) but you could be confronted with security and prompting, not advised anyway. On the serverside you can easily save a file in java. ExtJs could be run on the server in eg IIS but not to save files.